# R aggregate functionality (using PowerBI)

Tags: r, powerbi, aggregate

I'm using R within PowerBI to plot my data. I've got a data-set where there are there are names as a legend, and numeric values for the x-axis (setpoints) and y-axis (percent).
I've gotten so far in R as to plot the x and y axis - whereby there are multiple values (percents) for each setpoint thus I use the aggregate function to aggregate the values for each setpoint.
What I want to do is have the values to be able to flesh out depending on their name (a legend as such) so that if I had two names selected (via a powerBI slicer) it would show two different sets of points (coloured differently would be good). I also use the lines(spline(x,y)) function to get a curved line for these points. I would also like it to make an individual like for the points corresponding to the name. Currently, the data all merges into one when I select multiple names and I understand this is because the code is not taking it into account.

I haven't found any resources online on how to accomplish this, although it is a bit difficult to articulate so that may be why (not knowing where to look).

I'll attach the R code below although I know it may not be of much use as there needs to be context of the data, although the dataset is very large.

```
# dataset <- data.frame(IDName, Value, Setpoints)
# dataset <- unique(dataset)

dat <- aggregate(Value ~ Setpoints, dataset, mean)
x <- dat$Value
y <- dat$Setpoints
plot(x,y, main ="Turbidity Frequency Distribution",xlab="% Time < Turbidity level", ylab="Turbidity (NTU)")
lines(spline(x,y))

#constant lines
abline(h=c(0.1,0.15,0.3), col=c("red","pink","purple"), lty=2, lwd=3)
```

Thanks in advance!!!